# How to build cockroach DB with customized CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS?

Tags: cockroachdb

I would like to build cockroach DB with `CFLAGS += -O`, `CXXFLAGS += -O` and
`LDFLAGS ?= -static`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to do that.

(1) If you are building with `make`. You can simple open the make file and just find and override these flags.

(2) If you are building with `bazel`. You can set these flags with these bazel command options: `--cxxopt=-O`, `--copt=-O`, `--linkopt=-static`. For example: `bazel build pkg/cmd/cockroach-oss --cxxopt=-O --copt=-O --linkopt=-static`

(3) If you are building with crdb's `dev` tool (a wrapper of bazel). You can pass in the same options as (2) but following an extra `--`. For example, `dev build oss -- --cxxopt=-O --copt=-O --linkopt=-static`